# Correlate between columns in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data frame with three columns which look like this: *Device,Bandwidth,Delay*

A device can be a PC or a Router. For each one of them I collected measurements every 2 minutes, which amount to 30 lines per device per hour. My goal is to correlate the 30 metrics of *Bandwidth* for every PC with those (bandwidth or delay) of the Router and sort the device list by correlation score to identify the most likely offender.

I am new to R but suspect this should be relatively easy to do. I appreciate your help.

Comment: cor(dataframe)  & have a look at this [Reference Card](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf) to help you start R.

Comment: From what I understand of the question, `cor(dataframe)` is not what they want (and this will produce a "'x' must be numeric" error anyway, due to the Device column). I think the OP wants to calculate `cor( df$Bandwidth[df$Device==GROUP_NAME], df$Bandwidth[df$Device=Router)` for each `GROUP_NAME` in `df$Device` that isn't Router.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to transform the data,
for instance with `dcast`,
before computing the correlations.

```
# Sample data
n <- 20
k <- 5
devices <- data.frame(
  Time      = rep(1:n,k),  # Make sure there is a primary key
  Device    = rep(LETTERS[1:k], each=n),
  Bandwidth = rlnorm(k*n),
  Delay     = rlnorm(k*n)
)

# Compute the correlations. I assume that "A" is the router.
library(reshape2)
delays    <- dcast( devices, Time ~ Device, value.var="Delay"     )[,-1]
bandwidth <- dcast( devices, Time ~ Device, value.var="Bandwidth" )[,-1]
cor( delays,    delays$A    ) 
cor( bandwidth, bandwidth$A )
```